# useContext does not store my data and gives me the default one even set

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have a problem , i've set my `useContext` with `useState` values in the provider , but when i import them and try to change the value , it change locally and not globally !

Login.js

```
import { UserContext } from './context/UserContext';


const loginD = (setStatue , username , password, user , setUser) => {
        axios.post("http://localhost:5050/login", {
            username : username,
            password : password
        }).then(response =>{
            if(response.data.statue)
            {
                setStatue(response.data.statue);
            }
            if(response.data.message)
            {
                setUser({
                    ...user,
                    _id : response.data.message[0].id,
                    username : response.data.message[0].username,
                    password : response.data.message[0].password,
                    name : response.data.message[0].name
                })
                console.log(user);//{id : "the id", username : "username" , password : "password"}
                localStorage.setItem("jwt", "logged in");
                setStatue("Succesfully Logged in");
            }
        })
}
```

Home.js

```
const Home = () => {
    const [user , setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(user)} //{id:"",username:"",password:""}
            <p>Hello {user.username}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

UserContext.js

```
import React , {useState ,createContext} from "react";


export const UserContext = createContext({});

export const UserProvider = (props) => {
    const [user , setUser] = useState(
        {
            _id : "",
            username : "",
            password : "",
            name : ""
        }
    );
    return(
        <UserContext.Provider value = {[user, setUser]}>
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

it actually gives me the default values of the `useState` variable
can someone explain to me what actually wrong !
**thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest rereading the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) documentation. While it isn't clear from your question, I have the feeling you're missing `UserContext.Provider` and aren't using contexts properly. You also mention you're using `useState` but you don't show us where.

Comment: hello i updated the UserContext.js if this could help to make you further understand my probleme

Comment: @MH15O I assume you are doing `<UserProvider> ... <Home/> ... </UserProvider>` somewhere?

Comment: I don't see `loginD` being called anywhere. Are you sure it's being called? You can always add `console.log`s in places to make sure (or use breakpoints)

Comment: it's called when the button "login" is  clicked , actually when clicked the statue change successfully , the user variable from the useState is changed successfully , but when i go to /home the variable user from the useState return default values

Comment: Then the only other thing I can think of is that your `UserContext.Provider` (or `UserProvider`) gets unmounted and remounted during navigation, resetting the state. You can use `useEffect(() => { console.log('mount'); return () => console.log('unmount'); }, [])` to log when your provider gets (un)mounted.